# Checking the continuity of the real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ then we define $\lVert x \rVert_p:= \sqrt[p]{\sum_i |x_i|^{p}}$. Let $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{\lVert x \rVert _p \lVert x \rVert _n}{\lVert x \rVert _q} & x\ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0  \end{cases}$.

I need to determine whether this function is continuous for all $p,q$. I am not sure how to do this in general. When $n=1$, we need to consider the parity of $p$ and $q$ and it turns out to be continuous.

Do I need to proceed by induction here? I would appreciate it very much if someone drops a hint.

Comment: Check that the functions $||x||_p$ are continuous, then use continuity rules for products and quotients of cont. functions to see that the function is cont. for $x \neq 0$. Then check continuity at $x=0$ "by hand".

Comment: @newGuy Does B. Swan's comment make sense to you? Can you see how to answer this question now, or are you still stuck?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes it does make sense. I was wondering whether when $x=0$ I can use of the fact that two norms in $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent to finish the job. Would that be okay?

Comment: @newGuy Yes, it does

Comment: For $q$ odd and $n>1$ the function has multiple discontinuities because $||x||_q$ can be 0 for nonzero $x$.

Comment: @newGuy I just noticed that your definition is strange. Typically, we have
$$
\|x\|_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum_i |x_i|^p}, 
$$
but you have omitted the absolute value. Is this intentional?